# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 20.0 Gb

Tags: r, memory, k-means

I'm running **kmeans** using the following code in **RStudio (Version 1.3.1093)**:

```
km.res <- eclust(df, "kmeans", k = 3, nstart = 25, graph = FALSE)
```

but keep getting this error message: `cannot allocate vector of size 20.0 Gb`

My df has a dimension of 74000 rows x 120 cols, the object size is

> object_size(df)
> 34.9 MB
> mem_used()
> 487 MB

I even tried to reduce the cols from 120 to 5 but am still getting the exact same error message. I'm wondering how the vector of size 20.0 Gb was calculated, and why reducing the number of columns significantly from 120 to 5 had no help with getting the vector size smaller?

I run these on my local desktop, with the following specs:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 16.0 GB

Would appreciate it if anyone could help with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although your data frame may only be 487 MB the computational cost associated with running such a k-means model appears to be greater than the RAM you have.